# How to specify ansible .retry file location per playbook

Tags: ansible

I've created a playbook that does a simple maintenance task and I want it to spit out a .retry file when that task didn't work as expected, which the admin can then use to troubleshoot the hostnames within. This playbook is stored in git for the whole team to use. Unfortunately by default ansible will store the .retry file inside the same folder the playbook lives which is undesirable as it will create garbage to cleanup inside the git repo (even if uncommited).

I know I can change the ansible.cfg file to put the retry file elsewhere, but I want to avoid having to ask everyone in their team to modify their configuration, and optimally I want to specify inside the playbook the location to store its .retry file, so that I could put it in a common location with other logs created by the same play.

Is there a way to specify the .retry location within the playbook?

Comment: You can add the `ansible.cfg` to the repo containing the playbook...

Comment: So I would need one directory per-playbook?

Answer (score 0):

you can export

```
"ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_SAVE_PATH=/your/centralised_preferred/location/"
```

prior to your playbook execution or set it as an environment variable (Based on your use case).

Comment: Thanks, but still not exactly what I need as this would still require each tech to manually set this variable before execution. I'm trying to make it more fool-proof than that.